# Model predictions offline different from Custom Vision Portal quick test

Tags: python, azure, tensorflow, object-detection-api, microsoft-custom-vision

I trained a model of Object Detection using Azure Custom Vision and the predictions done using 'quick test' in the portal are different from the ones obtained offline (with the sample code provided).

#### Project info

**Domains:** 'General (compact)'

**Export Capabilities:** 'Basic platforms (Tensorflow, CoreML, ONNX, ...)'

When I exported the file selected: "Tensorflow" > "Tensorflow"

#### Original Image

[image]

#### Quick Test (CV Portal)

I used a dataset of 50 images of cats only.
In the portal I got the following result:

[image]

#### Offline Prediction

[image]

(For box visualization I added the following code to the main method in 'prediction.py' sample code provided in the export .zip file)

```py
print("Predictions[0]", predictions[0]['boundingBox']['left'])
    image_cv = cv2.imread(image_filename)
    HEIGHT, WIDTH, channels = image_cv.shape
    for i in range(len(predictions)):
        print(predictions[i], "\n")
        # TESTING#
        x1, y1 = predictions[i]['boundingBox']['left'], predictions[i]['boundingBox']['top']
        x2, y2 = x1 + predictions[i]['boundingBox']['width'], y1 + predictions[i]['boundingBox']['height']
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = round(x1 * WIDTH), round(y1 * HEIGHT), round(x2 * WIDTH), round(y2 * HEIGHT)

        image_cv = cv2.rectangle(image_cv, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color=(0, 0, 0), thickness=1)

        # show_names and show_percentage:
        label = "%s : %.3f" % (predictions[i]['tagName'], predictions[i]['probability'])

        b = np.array([x1, y1, x2, y2]).astype(int)
        cv2.putText(image_cv, label, (b[0], b[1] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, (100, 0, 0), 3)
        cv2.putText(image_cv, label, (b[0], b[1] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, (255, 255, 255), 1)

    cv2.imwrite("Predicted-img.jpg", image_cv)
```

Can someone help me find what went wrong? I can provide the 'model.pb' file and the sample codes provided if needed. I'm not sure if I messed up the export settings or other little detail.

[Here](https://github.com/danieltarita/Azure-CV) is the link to the repo with my project, it might help

And a [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/97129/model-predictions-offline-different-from-custom-vi.html) to the Microsoft Q&A issue I opened